# How to check the validation when user moves from one textfield to another in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 6 textfields in my signup page for entering Username, Institution Id, Email, Mobile, Country, City. Currently, the validation mode is given as,

```
AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
```

So, I want to change this mode, such that, when i complete the Username and move to the Institution Id field, validation should be active for Username. And this should happen for every other textfields. So, can anybody help me with a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add focusnode and listener for each textField. Validatation can be done onFocus of the textField. For example

```
FocusNode userFocusNode = FocusNode();
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  userFocusNode.addListener(() {
  if (userFocusNode.hasFocus) {
     //write your validate function

     } 
   });
}
```

In your textField mention the focusNode

```
TextField(
        focusNode: userFocusNode,
```